# Как повесить сервер на url

Tags: node.js

Создал простенький сервер на NodeJS. Как его повесить на нужный url, а не на порт?

Comment: видимо не url а domain?

Comment: @Vladimir VG, Скорее даже `Virtual Host`

Comment: @niki-timofe к всеобщей радости apache не единственный веб сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы по адресу `mysite.loc` у вас в локалке был ваш сервер (вы ведь хотите, чтобы другие люди в локалке ходили на него по этому адресу?) вам надо заняться не node.js-ом, а подниманием в локалке своего DNS-сервера, который по запросу `mysite.loc` будет отдавать ваш IP-адрес в локальной сети. Тогда любой запущенный у вас сервер будет доступен по этому же адресу (при соответствующих настройках фаервола).

---

**UPD0.** 
В случае если у вас несколько экземпляров `node.js` и каждый должен откликаться на свой hostname, поставьте перед нодами nginx.

Вопрос, на самом деле, для [РутКода](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: @Nofate, хорошо, на комп ТС'а через `DNS` сервер попали люди, а у него там **2 сервера, и оба откликаются на любой адрес**, хоть **`mysite.loc`**, хоть **`yoursite.loc`**, как тогда быть???

Comment: Не совсем. Мне нужно чтобы мой сервер был доступен только для меня(localhost), подобно денверу.

Comment: > а у него там 2 сервера, и оба откликаются на любой адрес

@niki-timofe, про два сервера (насколько я могу видеть) нигде не говорилось. Но и это не проблема: перед инстансами `node.js` ставится `nginx`.

>  нужно чтобы мой сервер был доступен только для меня(localhost)

@LightShock, тогда DNS-сервер замените на файл `hosts`.

Comment: Что значит заменить? Вы имеете в виду сделать перенаправление?

Answer (score 0):

- Вы имеете ввиду, сделать *назначение по хосту*, как в **`Apache`**?
- Если да, то вам [сюда](http://nodejs.ru/doc/v0.4.x/http.html#http.createServer) (От **`http.createServer([requestListener])`** до **`server.listen(path, [callback])`**)

Comment: Если честно, то я не знаю, как это называется)
Если проще, то мне нужно, чтобы по адресу http://mysite.loc был мой сервер.
P.S. всё делаю на локалке.

Comment: > как в Apache

Как в HTTP 1.1

Comment: @LightShock, это значит, что в **`server.listen(port, [hostname], [callback])`** Вам нужно указать **`port`**, он будет `80`, и **`hostname`**, он будет *mysite.loc*

Comment: Выдаёт ошибки.
Скрин: http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120603/aA9gKVTZ.png
В первый раз код был таким:
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80,'mysite.loc');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

Во второй раз всё тоже самое, только слушатель такой стал: .listen(80,'mysite.loc', function() { console.log('looooggg..');});

Comment: @LightShock - вам бы о http почитать для начала, если вы на это пойти не можете - пишите на PHP =)

Comment: На пхп я уже писал. Стал неинтересен, да и перспектив меньше. Вот и решил попробовать что-то более сложное)

Comment: Если вы хотите попробовать что-то более сложное, вы должны обладать необходимыми базовыми знаниями и желанием, если вы думаете что вы сможете освоить новую технологию на, хоть более-менее, приемлимом уровне не приложив для этого должных усилий, то вы ошибаетесь.

PS: вообще даже (нормальный)начинающий PHP программист должен понимать как нормально сформулировать вопрос и не писать "повесить сервер на url"

Comment: @AlexWindHope Мне вот кажется, что некоторым кажется, что научится что-то (программировать, если говорить об этом форуме) делать можно перепрыгнув через какие-то основы. Вот что значит "перспектив меньше" у следующего комментария?

Comment: @niki-timofe - причем тут "как в Apache"?

По поводу перспектив, как я понимаю, речь идет о планке зароботной платы PHP программиста, у JS программиста она выше, у серверного JS программиста - еще выше.

Правда с таким подходом можно вообще не учить, все-равно бессмысленно...

Comment: AlexWindHope, спасибо большое, вы ну очень сильно помогли!